# How can I make this list of queries shorter?

Tags: c#

I just want to hear if there is an easier way doing this.

```
public void Model(string _model)
        { 
            var list =
                    from vehicle in vehiclesorted
                    where vehicle.Model == _model
                    orderby vehicle.Price
                    select vehicle;
            vehiclesorted = list.ToList();
        }

        public void Brand(string _brand)
        {
            var list =
                    from vehicle in vehiclesorted
                    where vehicle.Brand == _brand
                    orderby vehicle.Price
                    select vehicle;

            vehiclesorted = list.ToList();
        }

        public void Mph(int _mph)
        {
            var list =
                from vehicle in vehiclesorted
                where vehicle.Mph <= _mph
                orderby vehicle.Price
                select vehicle;

            vehiclesorted = list.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: I would write that type of thing as an extension method

Comment: Looks pretty easy and succinct to me. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why are they mutating a property/field instead of just returning the calculated value? Yikes.

Comment: What is `vehiclesorted`? Where is this data going?

Comment: that i got 6 more just like it and I thought there was and easier way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could refactor this into a method which takes the predicate for filtering:

```
private void CreateSortedList(Func<Vehicle, bool> predicate)
{
    vehiclesorted = vehiclesorted.Where(predicate).OrderBy(v => v.Price).ToList();
}
```

Then the calls become:

```
public void Mph(int _mph)
{
    CreateSortedList(v => v.Mph <= _mph);
}
public void Brand(string _brand)
{
    CreateSortedList(v => v.Brand == _brand);
}
```

That being said, making multiple public methods which each filter on a single private collection does seem like an odd design choice, especially since subsequent calls filter the *previously filtered results*.  You likely want to filter the original list each time.

It's also typically a good idea to consider returning the filtered results instead of mutating the internal list with each call.  This will provide a cleaner API and less surprise when using this class.

Comment: `filter the previously filtered results` I'd imagine this is a bug. I hope so at least.

Comment: @asawyer I suspect it is - which was part of why I pointed it out.  I didn't want to change the output while refactoring, but it just seemed wrong ;)

Comment: It might not be.  It could be something along the lines of multiple levels of filtered drop downs.  Each one restricts the size of the results further.  I know it's not as common, but it's not entirely useless either.

Comment: @Servy Yeah - I pointed it out, because it's a red flag, but didn't change it...

Answer (score 3):

Problems I see with your code:

- Methods should be called `FilterByModel`, `FilterByBrand`, etc.
- Why is `vehiclesorted` a `List`?  Store it as an `IEnumerable<Vehicle>` instead, and only convert it to a `List` when its values need to be read.
- `vehiclesorted` isn't a very good name - how about `vehiclesSorted`?
- You don't need to re-sort the list every time it is filtered.
- The inline LINQ syntax using lambdas is probably clearer here.

So here's how I would refactor these methods:

```
private IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehiclesSorted;

public void FilterByModel(string _model)
{ 
    vehiclesSorted = vehiclesSorted.Where(v => v.Model == _model);
}

public void FilterByBrand(string _brand)
{
    vehiclesSorted = vehiclesSorted.Where(v => v.Brand == _brand);
}

public void Mph(int _mph)
{
    vehiclesSorted = vehiclesSorted.Where(v => v.Mph <= _mph);
}

public List<Vehicle> Vehicles {
    get {
        return vehiclesSorted.ToList();
    }
}
```